# Python referenced function runs whole module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying my hand at a multifile python script for spotify. The user is prompted to choose from several options and a function handles each different option. Here is the `main.py` file:

```
import spotipy
import authentication
from tracks import savedTracks, topTracks, currentTrack, recentlyPlayedTracks

def main():
    print("Hello!\nWelcome to my spotipy project")
    client = authentication.authCode()

    try:
        actionItem = input("""
        Enter the # of the action you wish to take

            1. top tracks
            2. saved tracks
            3. current track
            4. recently played tracks
        """)

        actions = {
            "1": topTracks(client),
            "2": savedTracks(client),
            "3": currentTrack(client),
            "4": recentlyPlayedTracks(client)
        }
        print(actions[actionItem])

        return actions[actionItem]
        
    except spotipy.client.SpotifyException as e:
        print("======ERROR======")
        print(e)
        exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`tracks.py` file:

```
def topTracks(client):
    print("====TOP====")
    timePicker = input("""Please choose a time range 
        1. short-term
        2. medium-term
        3. long-term
    """)

    timeRange = {
        "1": "short_term",
        "2": "medium_term",
        "3": "long_term"
    }

    print(timeRange)
    print(timeRange[timePicker])

    results = client.current_user_top_tracks(time_range=timeRange[timePicker])

    topTracks = []
    for item in enumerate(results['items']):
        track = item['track']
        topTracks.append(track['artists'][0]['name'], " - ", track['name'])
    
    print(topTracks)
    return topTracks

def savedTracks(client):
    print("====SAVED====")
    results = client.current_user_saved_tracks()
    for item in enumerate(results['items']):
        track = item['track']
        print(track['artists'][0]['name'], " – ", track['name'])

def currentTrack(client):
    print("current track")


def recentlyPlayedTracks(client):
    print("recently played")
```

The problem I'm running into is that when the functions are called it will run all of `tracks.py` instead of the single function. I've been looking at [python module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) and similar stackoverflow questions and from what I've seen the way I've imported and referenced the functions are correct. I'm running on a pipenv shell using Python 3.8.6. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because you have called the functions prematurely:
While initializing your `actions` dictionary, python will execute those functions to know their values:

You may want to do something like this:

```
try:
        actionItem = input("""
        Enter the # of the action you wish to take

            1. top tracks
            2. saved tracks
            3. current track
            4. recently played tracks
        """)

        actions = {
            "1": topTracks,
            "2": savedTracks,
            "3": currentTrack,
            "4": recentlyPlayedTracks
        }
        print(actions[actionItem](client))

        return actions[actionItem](client)
```

**NOTE**: except `topTracks` none of the other functions in `tracks.py` return anything, so you are gonna probably have `None` while printing their values from `main` in `main.py`, still the functions would be called once, based on user's choice.